# How do I get around Access-Control-Allow-Origin error with ReactJS?

Tags: oauth, flask, google-api, reactjs

I have a flask backend set up that runs through Google's OAuth2 flow. When the user visits /signup, there's a button there they can press to start it up. I know that the flow works because if I set up it to start as soon as someone visits /signup (by doing a 302 redirect to the /start-google-oauth endpoint), then everything goes smoothly.

But if I remove the redirect and have the user start the flow themselves by pressing the button, it doesn't work. The button just issues a GET request to /start-google-oauth but then the redirect to google to open their popup window returns an Access-Control-Allow-Origin error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '<origin url>' is therefore not allowed access.
```

The origin specified as the origin url is however given as a valid redirect_uri in the app's credential setup.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Please show code and/or an example URL. The Google OAuth URL is not going to support XHR requests.

Comment: I know this was a while ago, but did you ever find a solution to getting around the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are forwarding a `GET` request try setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` before forwarding.